# How to modify, without any loop, a collections values to get a new collection?

Tags: java, collections, loops

How do I, without using any loop, modify the values in a collection to get a new collection with the modified values?

For example, I'm having a `Collection<String>` and want to surround all Strings by parentheses.

With a loop I would do this:

```
Iterable<String> collection = getCollection();
ArrayList<String> newCollection = new ArrayList<String>();    
for(String str : collection) 
    newCollection.add("(" + str + ")");
```

There has to be a more elegant solution.

EDIT: Use of third party utilities is allowed :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>no, there isn't. Using only JDK classes you cannot do it better.</strike> [Check my second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281607/how-to-modify-without-any-loop-a-collections-values-to-get-a-new-collection/1281757#1281757)

**EDIT**

try google collection library [Lists.trasform](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html):

```
List<String> out = Lists.transform(in, new Function<String, String>() {

    public String apply(String s) {
        return String.format("(%s)", s);
    }
});
```

Comment: Use of third party is allowed :)

Comment: +1 for the readability of this part: String.format("(%s)", s);

Comment: You're just passing off the loop, though.

Comment: The idea of "modifying without loop" is almost similar to "run application without executable", someone has to hide the loop somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CollectionUtils.transform](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#transform(java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer)) from Apache commons collections.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Apache Commons CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer%29):

```
List l = someList;
CollectionUtils.transform(l, new Transformer() {
    public Object transform(Object o)
    {
        String s = (String) o;
        return "(" + s + ")";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's sounds to me like you're trying to use functional idioms with Java. While this can be achieved using third party libs and functor (as others have suggested), I would recommend programming Java using Java idioms or use a functional language. If you want a JVM-compatible functional language, look at [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You want a [Map function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)). Those are available (among other things) in [functional java](http://functionaljava.org/). Example code:

```
import fj.F;
import fj.data.List;
import static fj.data.List.*;
import static fj.pre.Show.listShow;
import static fj.pre.Show.stringShow;

import static java.lang.String.format;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> a = list("a", "b", "c");
        List<String> b = a.map(new F<String, String>() {

            public String f(String s) {
                return format("(%s)", s);
            }

        });

        listShow(stringShow).println(a);
        listShow(stringShow).println(b);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I, without using any loop, modify the values in a collection to get a new collection with the modified values?

Why would you want to? As Java does not have closures, this is often more complicated, non-standard and more difficult to read.

You will note that your example is shorter and simpler than the alternative solutions and it uses standard java.

BTW: loops are still used, just not directly by you so the distinction is an illusion.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the lambdaj library

http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/

and you will discover a huge set of handful methods to manipulate collection in a DSL style without writing a single explicit loop

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a Java shortage which has been discussed a lot. In many languages you can do that in just one line of code using closures (or code blocks). For instance, in Groovy you can write it as follows:

```
newCollection = collection.collect { "($it)" }
```

I wish, we can do this in java 7.

Comment: clojures was rejected for Java 7

Comment: Oh, what a bad news! I haven't been reading the news for some months and I didn't know what was going on. I just searched for that and unfortunately, it seems you're true. http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/01/java7-updated

Answer (score 0):

[my previous answer was *functional oriented*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281607/how-to-modify-without-any-loop-a-collections-values-to-get-a-new-collection/1281617#1281617), now, meanwhile I'm cooking "spaghetti al pomodoro", I'm thinking about a more *object oriented* approach.

What do you think about an anonymous class implementation that overrides it's iterator with one that enclose it's element around ()?

```
public static <T> Collection<String> wrap(final Collection<T> collection) {
    final Iterator<T> iterator = collection.iterator();
    return new AbstractCollection<String>() {

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return collection.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<String>() {

                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return iterator.hasNext();
                }

                public String next() {
                    return String.format("(%s)", iterator.next());
                }

                public void remove() {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

### demo

```
List<String> in = Arrays.asList("aaa","bbb");
List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>(wrap(in));
System.out.println(out);
```

outputs:

```
[(aaa), (bbb)]
```

BTW this only uses JDK classes and uses no loops!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but Java has evolved:

```
// At least Java-16
var res = collection.stream().map("(%s)"::formatted).toList();

// Or with Java-8
List<String> res =
    collection.stream().map(s -> "(" + s + ")").collect(Collectors.toList());
```